# Selenium/Ruby writing code to check Web Element by of way Xpath

Tags: ruby, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, rubymine

I am writing in ruby code using `selenium webdriver` and I simply want to check to see if an element is properly displayed on a webpage. I am doing this by way of `xpath`.

```
@driver.find_element(:xpath, '  ')
```

I am not sure what to do beyond that. I have added displayed? into the code but it thru back a no such element error. Any example would be appreciated. For example, verifying the the Google image logo is properly displayed by its xpath.
Please advise

Comment: Are you using selenium though Capybara?

Comment: Can you give an example xpath you give (e.g. for the google logo in your example)?
besides: are you sure you need xpath? (I'd advice to stay away from it when possible and use css selectors instead, as it is usually better maintainable)

Comment: How are you defining, "properly displayed?" That can mean a lot of different things... if it's an image, you can check it's `.naturalWidth` using Javascript and if it's not 0, it's displayed on the page but that only works for images. The rest of the elements, you could wait for it to be visible... but again, it depends on how you define "properly displayed."

Comment: I am not using Selenium through Capybara, would you recommend that instead max? Right now I am writing Ruby code with Rspec and Selenium as my Webdriver. Would anyone else recommend Capybara as well?.....//*[@id="hplogo"] is the xpath for google logo on its homescreen. I simply for example would like to verify that element displayed. Also, I have chosen to use the xpath specifically for my test because I couldnt pull it up with a css selector.